# R Error with ADF test in Time Series Lapply

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I have a data frame with time series, and I am trying to iteratively test whether each is stationary. R is giving me a strange error that `if (interpol==min(tablep)) warning...: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`.

```
df <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(15405, 15406, 15407, 15408, 15409, 15405,
  15406, 15407, 15408, 15409, 15405, 15406, 15407, 15408, 15409), class = "Date"),
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
  VALUE = c(5.67, 3.45, 4.56, 20.3, 5.1, 5.67, 3.45, 4.56, 5.28, 5.1, 5.67, 7.8,
  8.79, 9.43, 10.99)), .Names = c("DATE", "ID", "VALUE"), row.names = c(NA, -15L),
  class = "data.frame")
ids <- 1:3

test<-lapply(ids, function(i) {
  if(!any(is.na(df[df$ID==i,3]))) {adf.test(df[df$ID==i, 3])} else {NA} })

Error in if (interpol == min(tablep)) warning("p-value smaller than printed p-value") else warning("p-value greater than printed p-value") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Thoughts on what this could mean?

Comment: A shorter way to write your code is `lapply(split(df$VALUE, df$ID), adf.test)`.  It also avoids the potential issue that `ids` could have a value that doesn't exist in `df$ID` (e.g. `ids <- 1:4`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because you're trying to estimate 4 parameters (constant, time trend, lagged x level, lagged x diff) with 3 data points.  Simply put, you don't have enough data to run this test.

You need at least 5 data points, if `k=0` and even more data points if `k>0`.

```
library(tseries)
adf.test(rnorm(5),k=0)  # works without error
```

Comment: Huh... very strange. But this is definitely helpful. Any word on where you read about this/how you figured out that this is the problem?

Comment: @OlgaMu: I started by debugging the `adf.test` code (`debug(adf.test)`) and noticed that one of the model estimates was `NA`.  Then, I looked up the model on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test) and read `?adf.test` (the Details section says it tests the first order autoregressive coefficient). Then I simply counted coefficients and data (you lose 2 obs from taking the lag and the difference).